# Shadow pass can't capture the shadow from emission

Tags: shadows

This can be solved using shadow catcher. I'm just curious why shadow pass can't deal it.

So if i use lamp/light then shadow pass works fine. it can render the shadow from that light as i expected. But now i don't use light object. I created couple of plane objects and give them emission shader material so they will act as area light which will create shadow.

The problem i found that this shadow created from emission can't be rendered as shadow pass. Is this normal ? or any setting that i miss to tweak ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. It is indicated in the documentation as well:

> Shadow[pass]
>       Shadows cast. Make sure shadows are cast by your lights (positive or negative), and received by materials. To use this pass, mix
>   multiply it with the Diffuse pass.
>   ([Blender 2.79 Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/settings/passes.html))

There is no reason for that as far as I am aware of, it is just programmed this way. It is possible to get the shadow information from other passes - for example adding diffuse and glossy direct and indirect or just diffuse and glossy direct depending on what you need.